# Rosh Hashanah Shofar or Minyan?

Tags: minyan, shofar

If one has a choice between going to a minyan for Rosh Hashanah that does not have a baal tokei'ah and another place where they have a shofar but no minyan, where should he go for Rosh Hashanah? (I would assume he should hear the shofar because that is a [mitzvah d'oraysa](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Shofar%2C_Sukkah_and_Lulav.1.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) while minyan is derabanan - even though being counted [among the people](https://www.sefaria.org/II_Kings.4.13?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) is especially important on Judgement Day.)

(If this is a practical question, CYLOR.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Rosh Hashana 34b](https://www.sefaria.org/Rosh_Hashanah.34b.11)

> וּמִצְוָה בְּתוֹקְעִין יוֹתֵר מִן הַמְבָרְכִין. כֵּיצַד? שְׁתֵּי עֲיָירוֹת, בְּאַחַת תּוֹקְעִין, וּבְאַחַת מְבָרְכִין — הוֹלְכִין לִמְקוֹם שֶׁתּוֹקְעִין, וְאֵין הוֹלְכִין לִמְקוֹם שֶׁמְּבָרְכִין. פְּשִׁיטָא — הָא דְּאוֹרָיְיתָא, הָא דְּרַבָּנַן! לָא צְרִיכָא, דְּאַף עַל גַּב דְּהָא וַדַּאי וְהָא סָפֵק.‏
> And if one has to choose between hearing the shofar and reciting the blessings, the mitzva to be among those who sound the shofar is more important than the mitzva to be among those who recite the blessings. How so? If there are two towns, in one there are those who know how to sound the shofar, and in the other there are individuals who know how to recite the blessings, one should go to the place where they sound the shofar, and one does not go to the place where they know how to recite the blessings. The Gemara asks: This halakha is obvious. Sounding the shofar is a mitzva by Torah law, whereas the additional prayer applies by rabbinic law. A mitzva that applies by Torah law is clearly more important. The Gemara answers: No; this seemingly superfluous ruling is necessary to teach that although in this town it is certain that the additional prayer will be recited and in this other town it is uncertain whether or not the shofar will be sounded, one should still go to the place where they know how to sound the shofar rather than the location where they know how to recite the blessings.